# Prevent deletion of detail record if master record is 'submitted for approval'

Tags: trigger, validation

I have two objects called opportunities and TEST__c. master objects is opportunities and child is TEST__c. I need to prevent edit and delete of TEST__c record once opportunities record are submitted for approval. Please can any one help me out for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1) Create a record type and read only page layout for the Test__c object.

change the record type in Test__c when it is opportunity is submitted for approval.

2) write a validation rule. to check for change in all fields in Test__c record when opportunity is submitted for approval.

In order to prevent deletion of child records you want to write a trigger.

Comment: You don't need a trigger to prevent deletion. You can create a roll-up summary of tests on opportunity, and write a validation rule that says the value of that field cannot be decreased.

Comment: Good work around

Comment: Thanks for your response Monish and Robin I agree your points. I am going to check your suggestion.

Comment: instead of changing the recordtype, use field update in approval process to set status__c field to 'in approval'